# ul li a not resize a li by text size

Tags: css

A have this menu:

```
<li id="menu-item-32"><a href="#"><span>Dekanát</span></a>
      <ul>
           <li class="line"><a href="http://****.**/dekanat/farnosti/">Farnosti</a></li>
           <li ><a href="http://****.**/dekanat/duchovne-spravy/">Duchovné správy</a></li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

But, if in the 2nd li have the longest text, is it this:

[image]

(The problem is in 3-4 2nd li!)

Its not set size....

CSS:

```
div#top-menu{
height: 36px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
background-color: #111;
background-image: url("http://****.**/project/wp-lop/wp-content/themes/LOP/img/nav-

bg.png");
}

div#top-menu ul li{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #e3d8c4;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 36px;
}
div#top-menu ul li:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
}

div#top-menu ul li:last-child{
    border-right: none;
}

div#top-menu ul li a{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #e3d8c4;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
div#top-menu ul li.active a{               
    color: #d99d4d;
}
div#top-menu ul li a:hover{
    color: #d99d4d;
}                                     
div#top-menu ul li a span{
    display: block;
}
div#top-menu ul li ul  { 
    font-size:15px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 36px; 
    left: 0px;
    width: 200px; 
    line-height: 29px;
    text-indent: 0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:0px; 
    background: #1F1B17;
    /*background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#515151, #333);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#515151, #333);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#515151, #333);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#515151, #333);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#515151, #333);*/
    /*-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;*/
    z-index: 80;
}                              
div#top-menu ul li ul li:hover {
    color: #e0a95f;
}
div#top-menu ul li ul li{
    float: none;           
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3d8c4;;
    border-right: none;
    position: relative;
    height: 29px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    text-transform: none;
}
```

How to fix it? :/ Thanx

Comment: Try to put your margin...padding in the a css properties, I think it's the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
div#top-menu ul li{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 20px; /* you can use padding instead of giving height */
    border-right: 1px solid #e3d8c4;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 36px; /* you do not need that */
}
div#top-menu ul li ul  { 
    font-size:15px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 36px; 
    left: 0px;
    width: 200px; 
    /*line-height: 29px; also remove*/
    text-indent: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0px; 
    background: #1F1B17;
    z-index: 80;
} 


div#top-menu ul li ul li{
    float: none;           
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3d8c4;;
    border-right: none;
    position: relative;
    /*height: 29px; / also remove it from here. */
    margin-top: -7px;
    text-transform: none;
}
```

I think it is because of the `height`

Comment: Maybe you can try to remove the `height` from `#top-menu ul li`

Comment: Ok, its a fixed, i disabled a height in ul li ul li (@agriboz thanx :) ) and only in the ul li seted the width to min-width... Thanx :)

Comment: i am glad that i could help :)